# Accessing Mongo DB from within Node

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I’m trying to connect to a database through node. I’ve got it working with smaller databases using a Mongo URL of the form:

`mongodb://[username]:[password]@db1-a0.example.net:27017/[DB-Name]`

When I switched it out to use a larger DB, using the Mongo URL of the form:

`mongodb://[username]:[password]@db1-a1.example.net:27017,db2.example.net:2500/[DB-Name]?replicaSet=test`

It throws a ‘ RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded’ error and won’t connect. This URL is the onlything that has changed between the databases.

I’ve checked the db details and can access it through RoboMongo / Robo 3T so the database definitely exists.

Trying to connect through Mongoose version ^5.2.10 using the following code:

```
function connect() {

    if (MONGO_URL) {
        mongoose.connect(MONGO_URL, err => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('error connecting')
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
    } else {
        mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${host}`, {
            user,
            pass,
            dbName,
            useNewUrlParser: true //depresiation issue
        }, err => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('error connecting')
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
    }
}

mongoose.connection.on('error', (message) => {
    console.log('connection error!') //This is logged
    console.log(message)
    process.exit()
})
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', connect)


connect()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to use a replica set. If so try to connect like following`

```js
var uri = `mongodb://${userName}:${encodeURIComponent(password)}@${clusterName}/${dbName}?ssl=true&replicaSet=${process.env.replicaSetName}&authSource=${authDB}`

var db = mongoose.connect(uri).then().catch() // Whatever inside the then and catch blocks
```

`